# How can I reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 14 instead of 15?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reference, windows-services, office-interop, excel-2013

I am updating a custom Windows Service that is currently installed on a Windows 2003 server. The service reads excel files sent to an email address, and writes to that same file. Installed on the server is Microsoft Office 2010, and the project for the original service referenced `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` version 14.0.0.0, which is installed in the server's GAC.

I'm using Windows 8.1, developing w/ Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, and have Office 2013 installed on my machine.

At some point while resolving some of the errors and warnings associated w/ upgrading a project from VS2010 to VS2012, the reference to the above was removed, and replaced with a reference to Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library, which I (possibly incorrectly) assume contains a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` version 15.0.0.0. Needless to say, the service runs fine locally, but throws an exception when installed and run on the server.

I need my project to reference version 14.

My question is, is it possible to download the appropriate Interop dll without upgrading to Office 2013 on the server, or downgrading to Office 2010 on my machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had a reference to the correct assembly already then you can probably set it back again. In your project right click on reference, add reference, then search for interop.excel on the top right of the window:
[image]

If the version 14.0.0.0 is found just enable it and disable the newer one. As you see I have the same situation with both of them on my computer.

If the search won't find the assembly you can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Comment: While I only had version 15 installed on my machine, the link you provided allowed me to download the appropriate dll. Thank you, Mitja!